# Resizing div's in an AngularJS directive?

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to resize a div with a background image (left) and a variable height description (right), but can't get it to work. Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHeneise/yThdV/)
. I tried several things with/without zepto/jQuery/document.getElementById ... nothing works.

```
.directive('resize', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.height(400);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: I'm seeing "no module app" or something similar.  To create the module you need to define it with the second, dependency list argument `angular.module('app', [])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use jQuery, AngularJS implements only a lite version of the framework, jqLite, which doesn't have a `height()` method. You can see [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) for the list of the available functions in jqLite.

In your case, for instance, you can simply do:

```
element.css('height', '400px');
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blackhole/A8tx9/)</kbd>

Notice that, as pointed out in the comment, your fiddle wasn't functional. I've corrected that problem.

Comment: Ok, works in the fiddle environment. Not within PhoneGap though. I suppose it has something to do with the DOM not to be ready at this stage?

Comment: No. The DOM is ready and computed in the `link` function, at least for the element and his children (see the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)). The problem is elsewhere, but we can't help you if we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure out what's wrong then. At least it's working on the Angular-side.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery:

```
jQuery(elem).height(400);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yThdV/1/)

Not too ideal though :(